# Dialog page disappears after about 2 seconds?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a page at http://elementmedia.design/vawe-app/www/index.html

The issue I am having is that a dialog should popup when the user is not logged in (which works), but then it disappears after 2 seconds. I've tried everything I can think of to figure out why this is happening but to no avail.

Anyone have any thoughts? Feel free to view source of the page of the live demo. Thanks!

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>   id giving me a HTTP404: NOT FOUND - The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier). error

Comment: This is an error because those scripts belong to the cordova application, when the app is compiled those scripts become necessary. For testing purposes on the web, it will return a 404 as the scripts are missing. I do know that this is not the source of the issue I am having however.

Comment: @MatthewWalker I noticed you have a `style` tag outside of the HTML. Also attaching to `#page1` ready, may mean other parts of the document have not completed loading; therefore, the focus is returned to the page and not the dialog.

Comment: Thank you @Twisty, I set it to $(document) instead and it seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise the following:

```
$("#page1").ready(function(event) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "login.php",
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == "false") {
        $.mobile.changePage("#login-page", { role: "dialog"});
      }
    }
  });
});
```

See: https://api.jquerymobile.com/dialog/

> You can open a dialog programmatically by calling the **$.mobile.changePage** method:
>
> `// Dialog loaded via Ajax`
>
> `$.mobile.changePage( "path/to/dialog.html", { role: "dialog" } );`
>
> `// Dialog present in a multipage document`
>
> `$.mobile.changePage( "#myDialog", { role: "dialog" } );`

Comment: Isn't $.mobile.changePage() deprecated as of 1.4?